# ddns and port forwarding on a huawei hg633

Tags: port, forwarding, huawei-mobile-services

Has anybody succedeed in creating a web server at home using a huawei hg633 router ?

I started by using the no-ip service and didn't get very far, as stated in [this document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjXx7P9pvXhAhXmm-AKHargDzUQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommunity.talktalk.co.uk%2Feigde79682%2Fattachments%2Feigde79682%2Ffibre%2F208594%2F1%2FDDNS%2520%25E2%2580%2593%2520Dynamic%2520Domain%2520Name%2520Service.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3g22IT7Pzvr0MeAzJ5iD2h) this router is not compatible with no-ip.
So I tried using duckdns, following the instructions in the same document but that didn't work either. I also read in [this relatively old post](https://forum.kitz.co.uk/index.php?topic=15635.0) that dynamic dns is broken on those routers. In fact when I save my ddns settings, the password looks truncated.
Any port forwarding I set on my router doesn't seem to work, but that's probably related with the problems above (?)

Anything else I could try here ?

Thanks a lot !

For the record, my web server works, I can access it from within my network.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. You can find more information about this site in the [help].